# How to solve Poisson 2D equation with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a Poisson equation in 2D space like this:

[image: formula]

Here is my attempt to solve it:

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')
f = sp.Function('f')
u = f(x, y)
eq = sp.Eq(u.diff(x, 2) + u.diff(y, 2), u)
print(sp.pdsolve(eq))
```

It gives an error:

```
psolve: Cannot solve -f(x, y) + Derivative(f(x, y), x, x) + Derivative(f(x, y), y, y)
```

Is it possible to use sympy for such equations? Please help me with an example if possible.

Comment: I can't help you with sympy, but as far as I know, this equation does not have an analytical solution in the general case. In addition, I believe that you need a boundary condition to ensure the uniqueness of the solution. What do you want to solve this equation for?

Comment: The boundaries conditions are zero Neumann on all sides. The purpose is simple I'm learning how to solve PDE. Currently I have a numerical solution with implicit and explicit finite difference schemes. I hoped may be I can do the same with sympy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the [PDE solver page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/pde.html#module-sympy.solvers.pde) you will find

> Currently implemented solver methods
>
> - 1st order linear homogeneous partial differential equations with constant coefficients.
> - 1st order linear general partial differential equations with constant coefficients.
> - 1st order linear partial differential equations with variable coefficients.

Nothing of second order. Which is not surprising, because such PDEs do not admit explicit symbolic solutions, with a few (mostly uninteresting) exceptions. (If the equation is really `Eq(u.diff(x, 2) + u.diff(y, 2), u)` with zero Neumann condition, then the solution is identically zero.) It's not only that SymPy does not know how to find a symbolic solution --- there is no such solution to find.

Comment: Thank you! What python library would you recommend to use for solving second order equations by [Finite Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method)? I saw libs like [Fenics](https://fenicsproject.org) and [fipy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/). They use [FEM method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) which is too much for my task.

Comment: That is a separate question, more suitable for [scicomp.se]. In fact, it was already asked at [Recommendation for Finite Difference Method in Scientific Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/2246).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this idea, where nt is the number of iterations of your Poisson solver and b is the source term. dx and dy is the step in x and y, and in the end we have the boundary conditions.

```
for it in range(nt):
    pd = pDF.copy()
    pDF[1:-1,1:-1] = (((pd[1:-1, 2:] + pd[1:-1, :-2]) * dy**2 +
                    (pd[2:, 1:-1] + pd[:-2, 1:-1]) * dx**2 -
                    b[1:-1, 1:-1] * dx**2 * dy**2) / 
                    (2 * (dx**2 + dy**2)))

    pDF[0, :] = 0
    pDF[nx-1, :] = 0
    pDF[:, 0] = 0
    pDF[:, ny-1] = 0
```